# How to unmarshal struct with html template?

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling, go-templates

I am trying to unmarshal JSON to my Mail struct, but Go returns an error while parsing html_tmpl and text_tmpl fields. **How can I solve this problem?**

HtmlTmpl field came from:

```
html, err := template.ParseFiles(pathToHTMLFile)
```

Here is basic example you can test

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "time"
)

type Mail struct {
    Id       string            `json:"id"`
    Subject  string            `json:"subject"`
    From     string            `json:"from"`
    To       string            `json:"to"`
    Date     time.Time         `json:"date"`
    HtmlTmpl template.Template `json:"html_tmpl"`
    TextTmpl template.Template `json:"text_tmpl"`
    Context  map[string]string `json:"context"`
}

func main() {
  mail := &Mail{}
  s := `{"id":"","subject":"Test mail","from":"support@example.com","to":"user@gmail.com","date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","html_tmpl":{"Tree":{"Name":"template.html","ParseName":"template.html","Root":{"NodeType":11,"Pos":0,"Nodes":[{"NodeType":0,"Pos":0,"Text":"PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9InJ1Ij4KPGhlYWQ+Cgk8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRleHQvaHRtbCIgY2hhcnNldD0iVVRGLTgiPgoJPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0idmlld3BvcnQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9IndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCwgaW5pdGlhbD0xIj4KCTxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IlgtVUEtQ29tcGF0aWJsZSIgY29udGVudD0iSUU9ZWRnZSI+Cgk8dGl0bGU+0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsCDRgdCy0Y/Qt9C4PC90aXRsZT4KPC9oZWFkPgo8Ym9keT4KCTxzcGFuPg=="},{"NodeType":1,"Pos":298,"Line":10,"Pipe":{"NodeType":14,"Pos":298,"Line":10,"IsAssign":false,"Decl":null,"Cmds":[{"NodeType":4,"Pos":298,"Args":[{"NodeType":8,"Pos":298,"Ident":["msg"]}]}]}},{"NodeType":0,"Pos":305,"Text":"PC9zcGFuPgo8L2JvZHk+CjwvaHRtbD4="}]}}},"text_tmpl":{"Tree":{"Name":"template.txt","ParseName":"template.txt","Root":{"NodeType":11,"Pos":0,"Nodes":[{"NodeType":1,"Pos":2,"Line":1,"Pipe":{"NodeType":14,"Pos":2,"Line":1,"IsAssign":false,"Decl":null,"Cmds":[{"NodeType":4,"Pos":2,"Args":[{"NodeType":8,"Pos":2,"Ident":["msg"]}]}]}}]}}},"context":{"msg":"Hi!"}}`
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), mail)

  fmt.Println(err)
  fmt.Println(mail)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) does not support marshaling into / unmarshaling from JSON. It's a struct with unexported fields, and it does not implement an interface that handles the marshaling / unmarshaling logic (such as [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)).

What you should do is include the *source template text* in your JSON and struct, and after unmarshaling the source template text, parse it as a post processing step. If you want to marshal a struct that contains a template, it should only contain the source template text (`template.Template` fields should be marked omitted, like `json:"-"`).